# Cannot migrate fresh laravel 5.5 installation - Could not find driver

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, laravel, laravel-5.5

I set up a fresh laravel installation on a fairly fresh windows installation.

**I'm using PHP 7.1.11**

When running php artisan migrate I receive (database is called "projects"):

```
In Connection.php line 664:

  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = projects and table_name =
  migrations)


In Connector.php line 67:

  could not find driver
```

I tried a normal MySQL database in a xampp landscape AND a standalone Postgres installation. Both result in the upper error.

I set up quite a lot laravel installations and never had a problem like this. It seems like some driver information is missing? Any ideas?

Update:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=projects
DB_USERNAME=garden
DB_PASSWORD=postgres
```

Comment: what type of database you are using?? show us your database configuration file

Comment: see pdo mysql enable in your php.ini file??

Comment: Have you changed `.env` configurations?

Comment: as said i tried both - mysql and pstgrsql configuration

Comment: @FrankProvost is your postgres or mysql service is running

Comment: It sounds like you're missing the actual Windows driver or the php-mysql extension

Comment: both services were running - how to install the php mysql extension?